# user input within while loop

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I was asked to run a loop that asks for user input, applies the change using the adjustPrice() method, print the new information after adjusting the price. and then finishes the loop when the user enters 0.

Right now it does all of the above, just doesn't ask for the user input again and ends with the printed new information. please help!

```
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
       System.out.print("Enter adjustment to price in percent (0 to quit): ");
       double adjustment = in.nextDouble();

       if (adjustment == 0) {
           done = true; 
       }else{
           swag.adjustPrice(adjustment);
           System.out.println(swag.toString());
           in.next();
       }    
   }
```

Comment: Should you be doing something with the input from `in.next()`? As of now, you're discarding it.

Comment: The final in.next() call will cause your code to have if the else statement is entered.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Hint: formatting and indenting matters. Spend the 1 minute it takes so that your output is as easy to read as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have in.next() at the end.  This expects the user to input something before the loop will reset to the System.out line.  Take out that line.

Answer (score 0):

to allow user input using the end

```
else {
   swag.adjustPrice(adjustment);
   System.out.println(swag.toString());
   in.next();
}
```

> but beware that this method does not take keys as enter or space to
>   take into account these keys use.

```
else {
   swag.adjustPrice(adjustment);
   System.out.println(swag.toString());
   System.in.read();
}
```